# numpy inserting axis makes data non-contiguous

Tags: python, numpy

Why does inserting a new axis make the data non-contiguous?

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4,order='F')
>>> a
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
>>> a.reshape((3,1,4)).flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> a[np.newaxis,...].flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> a.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Note that if I use `C` ordering, it does maintain contiguous data when I reshape, but not when I add a new axis:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> a.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

>>> a.reshape(3,1,4).flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> a[np.newaxis,...].flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

**update** For those who might find this in a search, to keep the current array order in a reshape, `a.reshape(3,1,4,order='A')` works and keeps a contiguous array contiguous.

---

For those asking "why do you care?", This is part of a script which is passing the arrays in fortran order to some fortran subroutines compiled via `f2py`.  The fortran routines require 3D data so I'm padding the arrays with new dimensions to get them up to the required number of dimensions.  I'd like to keep contiguous data to avoid copy-in/copy-out behavior.

Comment: @JoeKington -- Yeah.  I thought so too.  Since I discovered the `order='A'`, I can just use `ndarray.reshape`.  I'd prefer `np.newaxis` though as `data = a[newaxis,...]` seems cleaner than `data = a.reshape((1,)+a.shape,order='A')`

Comment: I'm betting this relates to the giant discussion on the numpy mailing list recently: http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Raveling-reshape-order-keyword-unnecessarily-confuses-index-and-memory-ordering-td33355.html  I certainly agree that it's confusing! I never would have guessed that slicing with `newaxis` would do that!

Comment: @mgilson just to add: you don't have to add a new axis to see this behaviour. `np.swapaxes`,  `np.reshape`, `np.transpose` all make the data `C_CONTIGUOUS` by default...

Comment: I am not sure why you need the order parameter. But if it makes you happy, it is basically just the flags being overly strict, and starting with 1.8. numpy can be compiled with a relaxed strides checking which will become default eventually.

Comment: Ah, yeah ok, without the order, it would fill the strides in a way that the flags get mangled again...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question but may be of some use:
You can also make use of **[numpy.require](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.require.html)**
`np.require(a[np.newaxis,...], requirements='FA').flags`
`C_CONTIGUOUS : False`
`F_CONTIGUOUS : True`
`OWNDATA : True`
`WRITEABLE : True`
`ALIGNED : True`
`UPDATEIFCOPY : False`